# managing code supporting multiple devices

Tags: c#, ios, servicestack

I have a web app which uses web services from a .NET backend. The same services are also used by an iOS app for a mobile app. The conundrum we are facing is that in order to use the web services, it means the iOS app must have an internet connection.

Ideally the iOS app should be usable when there's no network connection, however in order to do this, the app would need to duplicate quite a bit of the logic from the server. This is obviously not ideal as it means there is a possibility the code bases could go out of sync, etc.

I was wondering what paths have people taken to tackle this? Or are we doomed to maintain multiple code bases specific to the devices we plan to support?

Answer (score 0):

You need to build a cross-platform library. .NET Framework Portable Class Library is what you are looking for.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg597391%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at ServiceStack's [HelloMobile example project](https://github.com/ServiceStackApps/HelloMobile) which shares the [ServiceModel](https://github.com/ServiceStackApps/HelloMobile/tree/master/src/ServiceModel) DTO .dll and the [Shared.Client](https://github.com/ServiceStackApps/HelloMobile/tree/master/src/Shared.Client) PCL projects on each supported mobile platform.

Answer (score 0):

What's wrong with the iOS app requiring Internet access? Your users are going to absolutely need Internet access to download your app in the first place. It is perfectly acceptable for your app to require an Internet connection when it launches for the first time.

If you wish for your app to have offline capabilities, you can take a look at using a persistence mechanism. Core Data and Realm come to mind. If you wish to ship your application with some version of the data, you can manually add a seed data set when compiling the app. Both Core Data and Realm support this.

Comment: There's no problems in having offline capabilities for data storage. The issue is when we need to maintain application logic which is dependent on a web service. E.g., I have a button that calls a web service and this service relies on logic based on historical information which may not be on the phone.

To do this on the phone would require storing historical information on the phone as well as duplicating the logic contained within that service. I hope that makes sense..